# Why does zooming out of my canvas increase the image quality on js canvas?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas

I am making a card game utilizing Javascript Canvas with react, and I am wondering why the following thing keeps happening:

This is what my game looks like when I have the tab zoomed in at 100%:
[image]
And this is what it looks like zoomed in at 50% :
[image]

Although it may not look like there is much of a difference when i post screenshots, there is a clear difference on my end with the image quality. Even though the cards take up the same physical space on the screen, they seem to have a higher resolution, why is this? how can I fix it so that the image is always at the highest possible resolution?

I don't know if I should include code, this is a pretty large project so I don't know what I should even include and Im hoping for maybe a general diagnosis on the issue.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the canvas API to create the elements that look "low res"? Canvas can't rescale images.

Comment: @Andrew Im using ctx.drawImage() on a react canvas component

Comment: You are on a high-resolution monitor? Does your code takes `devicePixelRatio` into account? Without saying anything of your code we really can't help you.

Comment: @Seb The numbers? The words "power cards", "card", "back"? The recycle icon? The image on the card? The description text on the card? Are you saying those are all made with the canvas API? Applying an image using the canvas API and creating an element using canvas are different things.

Comment: Pixel alignment us the cause of the blurring. Look at the lines at bottom of left right card stacks. A single pixel line is being draw over a pixel boundary causing it to blur across two pixel lines. Both image show this but for opposite stacks. You need to ensure images match canvas resolution. If that is a problem consider images as SVG or rendered via 2D API to give you better control over placement of fine details